# Заменить три блока if...else на более эстетичную запись

Tags: javascript, if

Есть функция, которая принимает необязательный параметр: любое число. Все работает норм, пока это число `!=0`

```js
function go(number){
    let x = number || 10;
    console.log(x);
}
go()// вернет 10;
go(20)// вернет 20;
go(0)// вернет 10, а нужен 0;
```

Проблема решается с помощью конструкции `if..else..else`, но для такой простой функции это слишком громоздко. Можно ли переписать как-то более эстетично?

Comment: Поделитесь, в чём суть функции? Точнее, что вы от неё ожидаете?

Comment: let x = number == 0 ? 0 : number || 10;

Comment: @GromovAnton Это минимизированная версия конструктора, который возвращает объект, с различными параметрами: ширина, высота, позиция по X, по Y. Используется для рисования на холсте.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```js
function go(number){
    let x = number || number === 0 ? number : 10;
    console.log(x);
}
go()// вернет 10;
go(20)// вернет 20;
go(0)// вернет 0;
```

Answer (score 12):

Можно воспользоваться уже доступными: [параметрами по умолчанию](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

```js
function go(number = 10) {
  console.log(number);
}
go() // вернет 10;
go(20) // вернет 20;
go(0) // вернет 0;
```